# Highcharts JS 'columnrange' chart value formatting

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, highcharts

How does one know if the 'this.y' in the formatting function of a Highcharts JS 'columnrange' chart is currently processing the label for 'low' or 'high'? I really want to be able to style the value differently based on if its the low or high value for the chart. Couldnt find the solution in the docs, although I found stuff like xLow and yLow.

If you know Highcharts then this question should make sense without me posting any code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after a lot of pain I found the solution to be as simple as adding a if (this.y === this.point.low)  in the formatter.